# Passing large string content as argument to exe through Process.start

Tags: .net, string, command-line-arguments, process.start

I try to use command line arguments to pass a large amount of data, but am only getting a single line of data. I am not getting the remaining data.

Here is the code of the sending program:

```
zpl = Printer.GetZPLString(json, true, true);
const string path = @"E:\karthik related\EXEC PROGRAMS\PrintServerHost\PrintServerHost\bin\Debug\PrintServerHost.exe";
string Ip = PrintersList[0].IPAddress.ToString();
string port = PrintersList[0].PortNumber.ToString();
string zp = zpl;
Process.Start(path, Ip + " " + port + " " + zp);
```

This is the receiving program:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args.Length > 1)// && (args[1].StartsWith("/n")))
        {
            System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
            client.Connect(args[1], Convert.ToInt16(args[2]));
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            writer.Write(args[3]);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

Can any one suggest what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line parameters are not a good way to pass data around for two reasons:

1. For Process.Start, the maximum command line length is 2080 charachters. [See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. If your string contains whitespace, quotes, backslashes or stuff like that, it will get corrupted. Those characters control how the command line is parsed. [See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Since you say you are only getting "a single data", you're probably hitting problem #2. You could try escaping all problematic characters, but that won't help with the length limit. It's better to use a temporary file to pass your data.